# Search the string Benmark time python

Tags: python, string, benchmarking

For my project I want to write a program that searches for a word in a string/long document in python.
If the word is not in the string/document, I have to search for approximate matches.

For example the word “brain”,
Deletions:  rain  bain  brin  bran  brai . 
Substitutions:  train  grain  blain  bryin ...
I already have deletion and substitution function, but I am not sure how to search for the word in Brute Force runtime/ Benchmark runtime

```py
string = "hereharewereworeherareteartoredeardareearrearehrerheasereseersearrah"
# the string can be much longer
Pattern = "ware"
# the output should have 4 deletion and 6 subtitutions


#string0 is Pattern, string1 is the word we compare, if it is the type, append to the list 
Deletions = []
def deletions(string0, string1):
    deletionlist = []
    #append list of deletion word
    for i in range(len(string0)):
        deletionlist.append(string0.replace(string0[i], ""))
        #delete first string and last

    if string1[1:] in deletionlist:
            Deletions.append(string1[1:])
            return 1

    elif string1[:-1] in deletionlist:
        if len(string1[:-1]) == 1:

            Deletions.append(string1[:-1])
            return 1

Substitutions = []
def subsitutions(string0, string1):
    if len(string0) == len(string1):
        sublist = []
        #append list of deletion word
        for i in range(len(string0)):
            sublist.append(string0.replace(string0[i], ""))
        for j in range(len(string1)):
            if string1.replace(string1[j], "") in sublist:
                Substitutions.append(string1)
                break
```

Comment: I don't think you have defined "approximate match" well enough. A single deletion? A single substitution? With an unlimited number every string is an approximate match.

Answer (score 0):

The best is levenshtein algorithm, you may calculate the distance between 2 words or sentences (how many character replacements it takes to convert one into another) or similarity ratio, if you like:

```
>>> import Levenshtein
>>> Levenshtein.distance( 'hello, guys', 'hello, girls' )
3
>>> Levenshtein.ratio( 'hello, guys', 'hello, girls' )
0.782608695652174
```

You may check the details of the implementation and other info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance